# Google Chart Crosshair

Tags: google-visualization

I'm using Google Combo Chart in ASP.NET MVC app.

Can I make crosshair not to the incoming data points, but to the horizontal axis, so I will be able to move the crosshair, showing the time at which it is now?

Comment: no, crosshair centers on the data -- [here are the options for crosshair](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/crosshairs)

Comment: Thank you. Is there a solution to get the time to make a div over chart div instead of crosshair?

Comment: not sure i follow, but you could try using [column roles](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles) `'annotation'` and `'annotationText'` for the x-axis -- `'annotation'` will show just above time on chart, `'annotationText'` will popup on hover of `'annotation'`

Comment: Okay, i'll try this.Thank you!